# Bash script for finding the square root of a number(Babylonian Method)

Tags: bash

I wrote this code to find the square root of a given x number, but the last part gives me "integer expression expected" , what can I do?
(I'm a shell/bash noob)

```
  #bin/bash
  2 clear
  3 echo "Hello, we will calculate the square root of a number x"
  4 echo "We're going to use the Babylonian Method"
  5 echo "Give me a valor for x"
  6 read x
  7         if [ $x -lt 0 ]
  8         then
  9         clear
 10         echo "The roots of this number are imaginary"
 11         elif [ $x -eq 0 ]
 12         then
 13         clear
 14         echo "The square root of 0 is 0"
 15   else
 16         echo "Now give me a base b and a vertical height h so that bh=x"
 17        
 18         echo "Give me b"
 19         read b
 20         echo "Give me h"
 21         read h
 22 fi
 23
 24         if [ $b -eq $h ]
 25         then
 26         echo:"b or h are already the square root of h"
 27         else
 28         until [ $b -eq $h ]
 29         do
 30         b=`echo "scale=3; ($b + $h)/2"|bc -l`
 31         h=`echo "scale=3; $x/$b"|bc -l`
 32         done
 33         fi
 34         echo "the square root of x is $b or $h"
 35
```

Comment: Feel free to take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash can only handle integers. The same applies to `[ ... ]` (check `man test`):

> ```
> INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
>     INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
> ```

In order to compare floats, use `bc` as you already correctly do for the counting.

Comment: You may end up in an infinite loop due to precision limitations even when using bc. Try entering values 15 3 2 for example (after you changed the until-expression to use bc).

Comment: Could you explain me how? I tried to do it but without good results

Comment: Try something like `if [[ 1 == $(bc -l <<< "$b == $h") ]]`

Comment: That works most of the times, but does not work when the difference between both numbers is almost 0 but still an aproximate value

Comment: @rulo1992: So, test that the difference between the two numbers is under a given threshold.